# leetcode 3sum assistance, how can i optimize this answer?

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I have a solution that seems to pass most of the tests but is too slow. If i'm not mistaken, the complexity is O(n^3) due to the three for loops.

My idea was to start at the first three positions of the array at i, j and k, sum them, and see if it adds up to 0.

**The functions objective is:**

Given an array nums of n integers, are there elements a, b, c in nums such that a + b + c = 0? Find all unique triplets in the array which gives the sum of zero.

**Note:**
The solution set must not contain duplicate triplets.

**Example:**
Given array `nums = [-1, 0, 1, 2, -1, -4]`,

A solution set is:

```
[
  [-1, 0, 1],
  [-1, -1, 2]
]
```

```js
var threeSum = function(nums) {
    var originalArray = nums
    var lengthArray = nums.length
    
    //sort array smallest to largest
    nums.sort(function(a,b) {
        return a-b
    })
    
    function arrayEqual(array1, array2){
        
        var equal = false
        array1.forEach((value1) => {
            if(array1 === array2){
                
                equal = true
            }
        })
        return equal
    }
    
    var sum = 0;
    var answerArray = [];
    //start from first digit and add from there
    for(var i = 0; i<lengthArray; i++){
        for(var j = i+1; j<lengthArray; j++){
            for(var k = j+1; k<lengthArray; k++){
                if((nums[i]+nums[j]+nums[k] === 0)){
                    if(!arrayEqual(answerArray, [nums[i],nums[j],nums[k]])){
                        answerArray.push([nums[i],nums[j],nums[k]])
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    return Array.from(new Set(answerArray.map(JSON.stringify)), JSON.parse)
};
```

How can i get around having to use three for loops to make this work (aka how do i optimize this solution?)

Comment: The OP is trying to solve https://leetcode.com/problems/3sum/

Comment: @CertainPerformance in the bottom line of my question i asked: How can i get around having to use three for loops to make this work (aka how do i optimize this solution?)

Comment: The problem does not mention the maximum value of `n`, but my assumption would be you need O(n^2) to pass all test cases. If you check the "Discuss" section of the problem page, you should find plenty of solutions with good explanation.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [3Sum leetcode algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50122096/3sum-leetcode-algorithm)

Answer (score 2):

Think this problem in this way. Choose any number from the array say `k`. Now you need to find two other numbers in the array which add to `-k`. The resulting sum of three numbers will be `k + (-k) = 0`.

So this problem is reduced to find two numbers in the array which adds to a given number which is `O(n)` using two pointers method if given array is sorted.

In a nutshell, sort the array, take each number (k) one by one `(O(n))`, find two other numbers with sum -k `(O(n))`.

Total time complexity : O(n) * O(n) = O(n<sup>2</sup>)

Answer (score 1):

You can solve the problem in a runtime of `O(n^2)`. Here is the solution using JavaScript

```
    var threeSum = function(nums) {
    var solutions = [];
    var target = 0;
    nums.sort(function(a, b) {
        return a - b;
    });
    for(var i = 0; i < nums.length - 2; i++) {
        if(i === 0 || (i > 0 && nums[i] !== nums[i - 1])) {
        var lo = i + 1;
        var hi = nums.length - 1;
        var sum = - nums[i];
        while(lo < hi) {
            if(nums[lo] + nums[hi] === sum) {
                solutions.push([nums[i],nums[lo],nums[hi]]);
                while (lo < hi && nums[lo] === nums[lo + 1]) lo++;
                while (lo < hi && nums[hi] == nums[hi-1]) hi--;
                lo++; hi--;
            }else if (nums[lo] + nums[hi] > sum) {
                hi--;
            }else {
                lo++;
            }
        }
        }
};
    return solutions;
}
```

Comment: why the - 2 on nums.length in the for loop? I'd get - 1, but 2?

Comment: Because the index of the first element can be maximum `nums.length - 3` and the maximum index of the second element can be `nums.length - 2` and the length of 3rd can be maximum `nums.length - 1`.

Comment: why you mentioned amortized?